# Avoid duplicates in firebase using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to save some users. However if I get the same user twice it is creating two different ids. Instead I want it to increment the counter by one.

[image]

This is my code and thanks in advance:

```
function resultOne() {
    firebase.database().ref("people").push().set() {
         name: username,
         counter: 0
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current data structure that means you'll need two steps:

1. A query to determine the push key for the user.
2. A transaction to update the counter for that user.

In code it's be something like:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("people");
let query = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(username);
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    snapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
      let userRef = userSnapshot.ref;
      userRef.child("counter").transaction((currentValue) => {
        return currentValue + 1;
      });
    });
  }
  else {
    ref.push({
      name: username,
      counter: 0
    });
  }
});
```

---

The above will work, but if your user names are supposed to be unique, I'd highly recommend using the user names as the key under `/people`, instead of generating a push key for each.

When the user name is the key, you won't need the query from the above approach, and it becomes:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("people");
let userRef = ref.child(username);
userRef.set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1));
```

Comment: I edited my answer to make the `increment` fully qualified, so you might want to try that. In general, the code may contain types and such, so it is expected that you do some legwork to troubleshoot problems. For example in the first approach: set breakpoint on each line and run it in the debugger. Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Did you search for that error message? Did you figure out which line of code gave that error message?

Comment: Ah, I now see that I left the `update` in the second snippet. That should've been a `set` since `update` expects a key *and* a value.

Comment: In the first code, I'm getting an error "ReferenceError: child is not defined". Also the "userRef" is never used.

Comment: That was a type, which I now also fixed.